# Synchronizing span and textarea scrollbars - scrollbar slightly off and pasting issue

Tags: javascript, css

I have a table set up in the following way, with each cell containing a span and a textarea:

```
<table>
   <tr><td class="title">Original File</td></tr>
   <tr><td><span id='ogline' onscroll="og.scrollTop=scrollTop"></span><span><textarea onscroll="ogline.scrollTop=scrollTop" onkeyup="linenumber()" id='og' onfocusout="linenumber()"></textarea></span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Along with that I have the following CSS:

```
<style>
span {
  width:93%;
  height: 100%;
}
textarea {
  width:92%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:black;
  border-width:2px;
  font-size:13px;
}
table {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.title {
  height:5%;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#009;
  color:white;
}
#ogline {
  padding-top:4px;
  overflow:auto;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:14.99px;
  width:6%;
}
</style>
```

What I am trying to do is have the scroll bar of the span and the scroll bar of the textarea synch up. I've somewhat accomplished this using the onscroll event listener with the following code:

```
onscroll="og.scrollTop=scrollTop"
onscroll="ogline.scrollTop = scrollTop
```

This has somewhat accomplished what I want it to, with the span being about a line off of where it should be. The greatest problem I am having though is when I paste a large amount of text into the textarea. This almost completely doesn't work, with both scrollbars being completely off until I hold one of the scrollbars down for a significant amount of time before the other scrollbar will try to play catch up with the other.

Any suggestions? Is there maybe a better approach to this issue that I should try? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work:

```js
var scrolling=false;

function og_scroll(el)
{
    if (scrolling && el!=scrolling) {
        return;
    }
    scrolling = el;
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for (var i=0; i<textareas.length; i++) {
        if (textareas[i].id.indexOf('og')==0) { // searching for id==og*
            textareas[i].scrollTop=el.scrollTop;
        }
    }
    scrolling = false;
}

function up(num)
{
    var area = document.getElementById('og'+num);
    if (area.scrollTop > 0) {
        area.scrollTop -= 15;
    }
}

function down(num)
{
    var area = document.getElementById('og'+num);
    if (area.scrollTop < area.scrollHeight) {
        area.scrollTop += 15;
    }
}

function fix_mouse_scroll() {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for (var i=0; i<textareas.length; i++) {
        if (textareas[i].id.indexOf('og')==0) {
            if ("onmousewheel" in document) {
                textareas[i].onmousewheel = fixscroll;
            } else {
                textareas[i].addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', fixscroll, false);
            }
        }
    }
}

function fixscroll(event){
    var delta=event.detail? event.detail : event.wheelDelta; // positive or negative number
    delta = delta>0 ? 15 : -15;
    event.target.scrollTop += delta;
    //console.log(delta, ' with ',event.target.scrollTop);
}
```

Html part:

```html
<tr><td> <span onmousedown='up(1)'>[UP]</span> <span onmousedown='down(1)'>[DOWN]</span> <textarea id='og1' onscroll="og_scroll(this);"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td> <span onmousedown='up(2)'>[UP]</span> <span onmousedown='down(2)'>[DOWN]</span> <textarea id='og2' onscroll="og_scroll(this);"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td> <span onmousedown='up(3)'>[UP]</span> <span onmousedown='down(3)'>[DOWN]</span> <textarea id='og3' onscroll="og_scroll(this);"></textarea></td></tr>
```

The full html code is [here](http://pastebin.com/NSk9CptY).

Comment: This solution is working well, however I am still having a problem when I paste a large amount of text into one of the textareas. With this solution, when I paste the contents of a file, in this case 237 lines, into the textarea I can no longer use the scroll buttons. I am able to use the up and down arrow keys and everything stays synchronized, however when you attempt to use the scroll keys of the textarea you are unable to move at all. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: the linenumber function is just something that adds a number to an outside div showing how many lines of text there are in the textarea, nothing that would affect synchronization of the multiple textareas

Comment: and by the scroll\span buttons, I mean the actual up arrow button and down arrow button that become active when there is a large amount of text in the textarea. Whenever I paste a large amount of data in a textarea that would activate the textarea, I am unable to move up or down in the textarea by pressing these buttons

Comment: @tRBK Hi, thanks for explanation. All this stuff can be made much easier with jquery, than with plain javascript, could it be possible? Here is [the updated script](http://pastebin.com/NSk9CptY) anyway.

Comment: jquery would work just as well, I was just making an initial attempt using pure JS. This updated script seems to work fine though. Thanks for all of your help.